# Как спарсить изображение на python?

Tags: python, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup, lxml

Не понимаю почему не могу скачать изображение с сайта html.

```py
import requests
import fake_useragent
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml

image_number = 0
storage_name = 1
link = f"https://actress-base.ru/?page={storage_name}"

responce = requests.get(link).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(responce, 'lxml')
block = soup.find('div', class_ = 'actress-list')
all_image = block.find_all('div', class_ = 'actress-photo')
name_actors = soup.find('div', class_ = 'actress')
nameall_actors = name_actors.find_all('div', class_ = 'actress-name')

for image in all_image:
      image_link = image.find('img').get('src')
      image_bytes = requests.get(f'{link}{image_link}').content
      download_soup = BeautifulSoup(image_bytes, 'lxml')
      dowload_block = download_soup.find('div', class_='actress')
      result_link = dowload_block.find('img').get('src')
      with open(f'image/{image_number}.png', 'wb') as file:
            file.write(image_bytes)
      image_number +=1
```

Прошу прощение если допустил какую-либо глупую ошибку, Я новичок, парсю для себя. Можете, пожалуйста, подсказать в чем проблема?

Ошибку такую выдает:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/elmizakhmedov/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/main.py", line 23, in <module>
    with open(f'image/{image_number}.png', 'wb') as file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'image/0.png'
```

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего вы не создали папку `image`. Проверьте папку `pythonProject1`.

Comment: Или [создавать папку](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12517490/8489602) при создании файла, если она не существует.

Comment: можно и так, но думаю легче просто создать заранее